# Laravel4 problems with JSON input

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I've a bunch of problems with this matter. Assume following POST (i'm using KnockoutJS to convert my object to json), where i'm posting inside http form data.

```
$.post('uri', {data: ko.toJSON(data)}, function(response){
      // Handle response
    }, 'json');
```

This is what's happening inside my controller

```
<?php
// 1. My plain input is here, and it's a slash-encoded string, 
// like { foo: \"bar\"}
$input = \Input::get('data');

// 2. Input::json() is empty, maybe because jquery 
// posts in the http form data instead of posting in payload.
$input = \Input::json();
```

So, to get my data out of the Input i have to

```
$input = stripcslashes($input);
dd(json_decode($input));
```

Assume that $.post() call **can not** be changed, i only want to approach this server side.

I think L4 should provide someway the parsed input, and i think i shouldn't be doing any stripslashes. So, what am i doing wrong?

**== EDIT ==**

Thanks to fideloper answer and comments, im gonna change something, since there's actually something wrong in the client side $.post (which, anyway, is not the point of this question). So, here's what new javascript will look like (data is still being posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

```
$.post('uri', ko.toJSON(data), function(response){
      // Handle response
    }, 'json');
```

What's happening now on server side?

```
dd(\Input::all()); // < --- Contains nothing (array())

dd(\Input::json->all()); // < --- Contains data array, as expected
```

What is confusing me is this piece of documentation, from [L4 Requests&Input](http://laravel.com/docs/requests)

> *Note: Some JavaScript libraries such as Backbone may send input to the
>   application as JSON. You may access this data via Input::get like
>   normal.*

In this case i can **not** access data via Input::get. Again: whats wrong?

Comment: I think problem is `ko.toJSON(data)`. Try send data without using toJSON method.

Comment: I won't add this as an answer because you explicitly said no client side modifications, but I'd just set the processData parameter to false in the ajax request. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

### Solution ( I think :D ):

Use:

```
$input = json_decode( \Input::get('data') );
```

Instead of :

```
$input = \Input::json();
```

### Explanation:

The [`Input::json()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L419)  method is attempting to grab the *body* of the request, and it's assuming it's in a JSON-encoded format.

However, the ajax call is not sending encoded JSON as the *body*, but rather POST parameters (which is not simply a JSON-encoded string).

Therefore, you need to grab the proper POST request parameter ("data", in your case) and decode that, since only the "data" POST parameter is actually a JSON-encoded string.

### Edit:

I'm not even sure the above will work. Since jquery is being told the "type" is `json`, it might actually send a json-encoded body. That could mean the relevant data gets encoded twice - once when `toJson()` is called, and again when jQuery encodes the data object.

Some investigation will be needed.

Comment: You are right about everything. Anyway, i already tried your solution and it will work only if i stripcslashes the input

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, I'm not sure of any other options. The client-side code is, in fact, "doing it wrong" - there's a clear case and argument for not JSON-encoding twice - if that can give you enough reason to have someone change it. (It sounds like that's not under your control :/ )

Comment: I changed a bit of JS code, and edited question with new details.

Comment: Interesting - I think you may be misunderstanding how `Input::json()` differs from `Input::get()`. A POST request will have a request body that looks like `foo=bar&foo2=bar2` (and so on with other parameters).  A request with content-type JSON should have a json-encoded body - something like `{ foo: \"bar\"}`. In your code, it therefore makes perfect sense that the POST array (which `Input::get()` grabs from) is empty, while `Input::json` returns the json-decoded data. The `get()` method searches for GET or POST parameters, while `json()` searches the body for json-encoded content.

Comment: Eh, my point is that Input:get should not ONLY be grabbing from POST and GET, since L4 docs states so. As far as i know, Laravel should merge those and work like an abstraction layer built over raw HTTP.

Comment: Ah, I understand your confusion (finally!). I'm not sure if that's a bug, an unclear statement within the docs, or something wonky with sending JSON post data in that manner. (You still are json-encoding twice by keeping `ko.toJSON(data)` in there, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you send an array like the following, this should work:

```
$_POST = array("data" => array("foo" => "bar")); 

$input =  Input::get('data');
$input = $input["data]";
```

If you want to avoid this, use the following javascript, might recheck http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (example 1: $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );): 
I am not sure about the toJson Part, maybe this would even work without toJson.

```
$.post('uri', ko.toJSON(data), function(response){
      // Handle response
    }, 'json');
```